# Why Using "< /dev/null" with a program like "bzip2"?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, bzip2, linux-from-scratch

`bzip2 --version 2>&1 < /dev/null | head -n1 | cut -d" " -f1,7-`

I saw this code in the LFS book, what is the purpose of the `< /dev/null` there?
I know `< /dev/null` is  used to prevent programs from waiting input by sending zeroes, but is it necessary here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is necessary.

As of the current version 1.0.8, `bzip2 --version` will print version info but it will also continue compressing `stdin`:

```
$ ./bzip2 --version
bzip2, a block-sorting file compressor.  Version 1.0.8, 13-Jul-2019.

   Copyright (C) 1996-2019 by Julian Seward.

   This program is free software; [...]

bzip2: I won't write compressed data to a terminal.
bzip2: For help, type: `bzip2 --help'.
```

When additionally piping through `head`, it'll simply hang, waiting for data on stdin. `< /dev/null` prevents this by presenting a zero-length file it can compress instead. (This does add some binary garbage to the end of the output, but it's filtered out by the `head` so it doesn't matter).

Debian (and its downstreams like Ubuntu) will [patch this out](https://sources.debian.org/data/main/b/bzip2/1.0.8-2/debian/patches/20-legacy.patch), making the `< /dev/null` unnecessary:

```
@@ -1916,8 +1918,8 @@ IntNative main ( IntNative argc, Char *a
       if (ISFLAG("--keep"))              keepInputFiles   = True;    else
       if (ISFLAG("--small"))             smallMode        = True;    else
       if (ISFLAG("--quiet"))             noisy            = False;   else
-      if (ISFLAG("--version"))           license();                  else
-      if (ISFLAG("--license"))           license();                  else
+      if (ISFLAG("--version"))           { license(); exit ( 0 ); }  else
+      if (ISFLAG("--license"))           { license(); exit ( 0 ); }  else
       if (ISFLAG("--exponential"))       workFactor = 1;             else
       if (ISFLAG("--repetitive-best"))   redundant(aa->name);        else
       if (ISFLAG("--repetitive-fast"))   redundant(aa->name);        else
```

But obviously, Linux From Scratch does not benefit from any distro specific patches.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase `< /dev/null` is **stdin** for bzip2. Quite possibly, it used to be required *or* just good practice to account for each standard stream and the author is old enough to still be doing it. The three standard streams are `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` and all are being used here.

I personally would do `bzip2 --version 2>&1 | head -n1 | cut -d" " -f1,7-` since `bzip2 --version` will not fail by missing `stdin`.

It may just be required for LFS. It is not required for Ubuntu.